# Javascript HTTP-EQUIV Does Not Seem To Be Working

Tags: javascript, php, refresh

I would like to redirect a page with two defined variables in Javascript:

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
        $task = $_POST['tasks'];
        $brand = $_POST['brands'];
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=brandmanagement.php?brand='$brand'&task='$task'>";    
    }
```

So the task and brand vars are getting from a form in the same page. But after doing the process I get this EMPTY url:

**brandmanagement.php?brand=**

So why is that, how to fix it?

Note that I don't want to use Header Location somehow!

Comment: Don't use JavaScript or Meta Tags to redirect a web page. Use [`Location: header`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) instead. Check [PHP the Right Way](//phptherightway.com/) for more up-to-date advice.

Comment: If you are intent on using it, you have a mix of single quotes in there that are fouling things up.

Comment: Don't put the single-quotes around your variables in the URL.

Comment: @PatrickQ @IncredibleHat If you mean this: `echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=brandmanagement.php?brand=$brand&task=$task>"; ` it still does not work!

Comment: Because thats still wrong. Watch what quotes you are doing, and where they are going. The three examples I have provided are clean copy-paste-able examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wish not to use the `header` function, then you should change this:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=brandmanagement.php?brand='$brand'&task='$task'>";
```

Into this:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=brandmanagement.php?brand=". $brand ."&task=". $task ."'>";
```

Or:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=brandmanagement.php?brand={$brand}&task={$task}'>";
```

Or:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=brandmanagement.php?brand=$brand&task=$task'>";
```

(although the last one is less readable and can lead to dangerous side effects as php tries to parse variable names)